# Harmony Collections Aren't Defined In NodeJS 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a `NodeJS` (v5.0.0), `Express` and `React` app.
I inserted a bit of isomorphism, so a few of my `React` app components get loaded in `NodeJS`.

The server crashes with the error: `ReferenceError: Set is not defined` in one of my `Alt` stores:

```
import alt from '../alt';
import NewProjectActions from '../actions/NewProjectActions';
import LoginStore from './LoginStore';
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';
import limits from '../../limits';

class NewProjectStore {
  constructor() {
    this.bindActions(NewProjectActions);
    //State
    this.activeStage = 1;
    this.projectID = null;
    this.projectName = '';
    this.hasActiveComponentFinished = false;
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.assessment = [];
    this.selectedClasses = [];
    this.assignmentsUploaded = new Set(); <------ THIS LINE FAILS

    The page goes on........
```

I tried replacing it with a `Map` and it crashes too.
The weird part is that you can see I'm using ES6 `import`'s and that runs fine.
I also checked the [`NodeJS` Docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) and it shows that Harmony collections are shipped with `NodeJS` without any runtime flags required.

I just updated my `Babel` so maybe that has something to do with it.
**Update:** just to elaborate a bit, I started using [`Require Hooks`](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#node).

Does anyone have an idea?
Needless to say I've went through Google already and found nothing.

Thanks for any help!

**Update:** I've tried using a `Set` in my `server.js` page and it worked. Seems like the issue really is `Babel` going through these pages, and not `NodeJS`.
I still don't know why it doesn't agree to ES6 collections.

Here's the full error stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: Set is not defined
    at Store.NewProjectStore (NewProjectStore.js:18:36)
    at new Store (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/node_modules/alt/lib/store/index.js:155:73)
    at Object.createStoreFromClass (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/node_modules/alt/lib/store/index.js:175:15)
    at Alt.createStore (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/node_modules/alt/lib/index.js:129:77)
    at Object.<anonymous> (NewProjectStore.js:99:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at loader (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:130:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:140:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/app/routes.js:17:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at loader (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:130:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ec2-user/projects/peer_reviews/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:140:7)
```

Comment: I believe you need a polyfill to use collections on the frontend even with babel.

Comment: The `Set` worked until now. In the browser and in `NodeJS` it's supported like `Array` is. And isn't this considered the backend?

Comment: I assumed that since you said it worked on your `server.js` page that this was the React frontend.

Comment: No, that's the weird part. It happens when I try to run the app. `Babel` goes through the `import`s and gets stuck at `NewProjectStore.js`.

Comment: I would guess that it has to do with some mistake your webpack config. Anyways maybe someone else has an actual answer.

Comment: Using `gulp` and `browserify`, they run fine.. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error related to `Babel`'s `Require Hooks`. The [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_register) say it's better for simple uses, and since `Babel 6` is so new I guess it's just a bug.

I fixed it by switching to activating `Babel` from the command line.
Instructions to activating `Babel` in various ways can be found [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#nodemon).

Good luck guys.